# The last digit of entered value is always 7 or 5 when entering a big number

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get the last digit of entered value in C++. Why the output is always 7 or 5 when I enter a big number e.g. 645177858745?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> a;
    a = a % 10;
    cout << "Last Number is " << a;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

Enter a number: 8698184618951

Last Number is 5

Comment: That number is too large to fit in an int. Always check if your input succeeded before you do anything with it. `if (cin >> a) { /* success, do whatever */ } else { /* handle failure */ }`

Comment: What happens if you hardcode your value instead of reading it from the user? That is, replace `int a; cout << "Enter a number: "; cin >> a;` with `int a = 8698184618951;`. Any complaints [or warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings) from your compiler?

Comment: @JaMiT that case is implementation-defined and may give different results to the stream extraction operation

Comment: @M.M The point is not the numerical result. The point is getting a warning from the compiler (which is why I specifically asked about warnings). Is there a major compiler that does *not* warn when assigning too large a value to an `int` (assuming common warnings have been turned on)? *Side note: this happens to also serve as a test to see if the OP is on an unusual system where `int` actually is large enough to store 8698184618951 and the problem is something else, something we don't see.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The largest value that an `int` (on most machines) can hold is `2147483647`

You enter `8698184618951`, which is bigger than `2147483647`. Because an `int` can't hold `8698184618951`, extraction will fail but `a` will now be the max value that it can hold. So `a` is now `2147483647`.

You should use a bigger type, like `long long` instead of `int`

So your code should look like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
// using namespace std; is bad

int main()
{
    long long a;
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> a;
    a = a % 10;
    std::cout << "Last Number is " << a;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value read is out of range for the integer type, then extraction fails but `a` is set to the maximum (or minimum) value of the type.

The size of `int` is implementation-defined but its maximum value should end in `7` for any common systems. If the exact code and input that you posted actually gives `5` then it could either be a compiler bug, or an old compiler. (Prior to the publication of the C++11 standard this behaviour was not mandated).  The `5` might be seen for a similar case but extracting to unsigned integer.